# How to hide an ApplicationView

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a UWP application, and it creates a second view like:

```
overlayView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
```

Then shows it which works fine.

I also want to hide the view when the user presses a button, but not destroy the view.
How can I do this?

My code is:

```
if (!isOverlayShowing)
{
    isOverlayShowing = true;
    if (overlayView == null)
    {
        overlayView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();

        await overlayView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, OverlayHandler);
        ApplicationViewSwitcher.DisableSystemViewActivationPolicy();
    }
    await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(overlayViewID);
    overlayView.CoreWindow.IsInputEnabled = false;
}
```

and the overlay creator is:

```
void OverlayHandler()
{
    overlayFrame = new Frame();
    overlayFrame.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
    Window.Current.Content = overlayFrame;
    // You have to activate the window in order to show it later.
    Window.Current.Activate();
    overlayFrame.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);

    overlayViewID = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
}
```

I tried to hide it with:

```
async Task<int> HideBlinkFrame()
{
    if(overlayView == null || isOverlayShowing == false)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    await overlayFrame.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        overlayFrame.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    });

    isOverlayShowing = false;
    return 0;
}
```

But that just hides the inner frame, not the window.

I see that `ApplicationView` has a `TryConsolidateAsync()` but `CoreApplicationView` does not have that method.

Comment: If you want to call `TryConsolidateAsync()`, then call `TryConsolidateAsync()`: Dispatch to the CoreApplicationView, and in the handler call `ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryConsolidateAsync()`.

Comment: That works, So then how does one UnHide the frame?

Comment: Not sure why this asking how to do something you know how to do. TryShowAsStandaloneAsync, like you do in the first code fragment.

Comment: Ah got it...                        Window.Current.Content = overlayFrame;
                        await ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterViewModeAsync(ApplicationViewMode.Default);